# How to get main type of generic field with reflection in java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, code-generation, freemarker

Assume that i have these below classes in my project:

```
public class MyBaseEntity<T> {
    T   id;
}

public class MySubClass extends MyBaseEntity<Long> {

}
```

and now, i want to get main type of `id`(`java.lang.Long`) field of `MySubClass`with java reflection, how can i do that?

**UPDATE**

i changed classes to this and added 2 new `Class`:

```
public class MySubClass3 extends MyBaseEntity<Integer> {

}

public class MySubClass2 extends MySubClass3 {

}

public class MySubClass extends MySubClass2 {

}
```

now, how can i get main type of id, in other word, if the depth of inheritance was dynamic how can i get the main type of `id` for a specific class?

Comment: You'll only be able to do that if you actually assign a `Long` to it. The variable itself is of type `Object` after type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the type to the constructor of the base class

```
public MyBaseEntity(Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can define in runtime which class was used for your `T` parameter of `MyBaseEntity` using the approach like this:

```
Type type = MySubClass.class.getGenericSuperclass();
if(type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    Type parameterType = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if(parameterType instanceof Class) {
        System.out.println(((Class<?>)parameterType).getName());
        // prints java.lang.Long
    }
}
```

But it's quite error-prone approach. You may have more tricky inheritance or use wildcards like `class SubClass<T extends Number> extend MyBaseEntity<T>` and you will have to handle such cases specially. Thus I'd recommend you to use the approach suggested by @Reimeus.

Comment: thanks, did you know how can i use that in freemarker templates?